# Match multi-line text between two tags

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am trying match some multi-line text that changes, between two tags. The only that doesn't change is the img and url tags. The number of lines change and is not the same every time.

Is it possible? Can you help me with the pattern?

Bellow is an example of what I have. With **bold** is the text that I want to match.

`[img]http://image.jpg[/img]`**`text text text text text text`**

**`text text text text text text text text text text`**

**`text text text text text text text text text text text text`**

**`text text text text text text text text`**

**`text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text`**

**`text text text text text text text text text text text text text text`**

`text text text text [url=http://url[/url]`

`text text text text`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For myself, I don't understand your question. You want to compare multiple lines... Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't want to compare something. I want to use javascript regex to match some text...

Comment: can you try this regex ^[^<>[][a-zA-Z\s]+

Answer (score 0):

you can try this regex

```
^[^<>[][a-zA-Z\s]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/iZTMwY/1